# unable to fetch updated variable from an active python module

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to create a module that would fetch a specific variable from an active module preferably as read only. I have tried importing the file in test2 but the print statement displays the length as 0. Cant understand why it is not able to get the current status of the variable and only reading the initialization.

Below is what I have tried, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

test1.py

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import time

data=[]
stop=datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=5)
while datetime.now()<stop:
        time.sleep(1)
        data.append(datetime.now().time())
```

test2.py:

```
from test1 import *
print len(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap statements in:

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

The code within only gets executed when you execute that specific module from the Python interpreter. So your Main function won't get executed, and consequently your data variable won't be initialized, unless you run:

```
python test2.py
```

You can actually just remove that clause and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Hope I understood you correctly. plz check the edited code. when I run >python test2.py it just executes test1 code and gets stuck in its while loop. All I need test2.py to do is give me the data variable back and exit. Basic requirement is to have test1 create and store values in the list and test2 to access the list in its current state for other purposes.

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. If you're trying to have a list in a different module that continues to update while you access it from test2.py  this is not going to work. You're going to have to have two different threads of operation and a queue if that's the case. Maybe you can shed some light onto what you're actaully trying to accomplish?